# DIV flickering caused by setInterval in Chrome jquery php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a website with a list of online users similar to Facebooks, where it shows when the user have last been active. My main problem is probably related to both jQuery AND PHP part, so i'll give you all details necessary.

**ACTUAL PROBLEM:** Whenever setInterval() function is being run by jQuery, my DIV with the content i want to insert flickers (looks like you'd refresh just the div). This only happens on Chrome, in every other browser, including Edge and IE it works fine.

**ANOTHER PROBLEM I NEED TO SOLVE:** Same as with flickering, if i select part of texts in the browser, and update happens, the selection if obviously removed. I'd like to know if there is any way to sole it so that selection remains where it was, but content still updates on given intervals (i have 0 idea where to even start with this one, so please if you have any tips or tricks and want to share i'll be thankful).

**SOME INFO:** Few thing i've noticed when trying to solve this (i'm pretty darn irritated, i'm not a skilled programmer and i spend 2nd day in a row trying to solve it): 1. Whenever i return only a simple string, it doesn't flicker. The moment i add HTML tags to the return, flickering starts, even if it is a simple  tag. 2. Magically, the flickering stops when i click anywhere on the page (huh, what?). It flickers when i refresh, and when i mouse click on any place on the website, flickering stops. 3. I've tested Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge and beta version of Vivaldi and none of them have the flickering problem, though all of them have selection-disappearing problem. 4. If you want i can provide a link to the page where i'm running this on. Keep in mind that it is a hobby project, so if you encounter fatal bugs and errors novice programmers do please don't hate me :)

So, here are the PHP functions i'm using.
Function that builds return string.

```
 public function returnOnlineList() {
   GLOBAL $db;

   $sql = "SELECT username, last_seen FROM users";
   $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute();
   $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
   $val = "";
   foreach ($row as $p) {

     $val = $val."<li class ='list-group-item' style='height: 50px; '><div class='whatss'><div class='nick' style='float: left; width: 64%;'><img class='img-circle' width='20px' height='20px' style='background-color: #eee; '></img>".$p['username']."</div><div class='active' style='float: left; width: 36%; '  >".self::lastOnline($p['username'])."</div></div></div>";



   }

  return $val;

 }
```

---

Function that calculates last online. Each user has a last_seen field in a database. This runs a query and then calculates difference between current time and last_seen time in minutes with TIMESTAMPDIFF.

```
public function lastOnline($value) {
  GLOBAL $db;

  // Calculating last_seen against NOW() on server to see when user was last online.
  $sql = "SELECT last_seen FROM users WHERE username = '$value'";
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $row = $stmt->fetch();

  $ssql = "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '$row[0]', NOW())";
  $sstmt = $db->prepare($ssql);
  $sstmt->execute();
  $rrow = $sstmt->fetch();
  if ($rrow[0] > 60){
    $retval = $rrow[0] / 60;
    $minval = round(fmod($retval, 1) * 60, 2);
    $hval = round($retval);

    return $hval."h; ".$minval."m. ";
  }

  else if ($rrow[0] < 10) {
    return "Active now";
  }

  else if (($rrow[0] < 60) && !($rrow < 10)) {
    return $rrow[0].' min';
  }

  unset($stmt);
  unset($sstmt);
  }
```

---

jQuery part. I have tried simply using .html(), got exactly same problem. There is no flickering caused by .append() and .prepend(). Flickering appears with .html() and in the case below when i empty() html element before writing to it.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  window.setInterval("updateOnlineList()", 2000);
});


function updateOnlineList() {
  $.get('?p=fh&ref=tests', function(data) {

    var stuff = data;
    $("#online").empty();
    writeTo(data);

  });
}

function writeTo(message) {
  var div = document.getElementById('online');
  div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + message;
}
```

---

I have been googling the past 2 days, found some threads that had similar problem, but nothing worked. Could this be caused by caching or something? I am not a very skilled person in these kind of things, so please be detailed in your answers. Thanks in advance! If there is anything else you want me to provide, send a reply and i'll do that.

Comment: that code's a mess. why are you using doc.getEleById when you're already obviously using jquery? And why empty, then do the writing elsewhere? why not simply have `$('#online').html(message)`?

Comment: Also, don't pass a string to `setInterval`, it's the equivalent of using `eval()`. Give it the reference to the function instead: `window.setInterval(updateOnlineList, 2000);`

Comment: @MarcB  - Because i have used both, none of them worked. This is how i have it saved right now, so i thought i'd post my current code. I have tried .html() without empty, i have tried .append with empty and i have tried .prepend with empty. Append/prepend without empty doesn't flicker, but i don't want to add to the div, i want to update its existing content.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Yeah, but that still doesn't fix the flicker...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval):

> Repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed
>   time delay between each call. Returns an intervalID.

The "flickering" effect you are experiencing with `setInterval()` is *normally* caused when the function is invoked before the it's completed its previous call.

You can mitigate this by using the self-invoking `setTimeout()`:

```
    function updateOnlineList() {
        $.get('?p=fh&ref=tests', function (data) {
            // only need one line...
            $("#online").empty().html(data);
        });
    }


    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(updateOnlineList, 2000);
    });
```

There is also a [known bug](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) in Chrome that may be causing this flickering to occur - or, at least,  would explain why it might be happening only in Chrome and not the other browsers.

For your second issue, I'm not sure what "texts" is but assuming it's an `input` element (or really whatever) you can tell jQuery to detect when the element loses focus using [`blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/):

**Full example:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var elem;

    // get the element that's lost focus
    $('input').on('blur', function () {
        elem = this;
    });


    function updateOnlineList() {
        $.get('?p=fh&ref=tests', function (data) {
            // only need one line...
            $("#online").empty().html(data);
            // set the focus
            $(elem).focus();

            // this line was missing originally...   
            setTimeout(updateOnlineList, 2000);  
        });
    }

    setTimeout(updateOnlineList, 2000);    
});
```

Comment: I apologize for late answer, was pretty busy these 2 days. Hmm, i did it as you said, but because of some reason setTimeout is not running every 2 seconds (or at least, contents aren't updating as they should). It only runs once when i reload the page.  Any ideas about that?

Comment: @Nae - sorry this was incomplete example. Please see update.